# How can I define i18n language code (same language but different version) in React?

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next

I have a problem about defining different kind of language through i18n in my React App.

I have **es-MX**, **es-ES** , **zh-CN** and lastly **zh-TW** language codes in my language array.

I have no idea how I can define them in i18n process.

How can I do that?

Here is my i18n code snippet shown below.

import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

```
i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    resources: {
         ...
    },
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    ns: ['translations'],
    defaultNS: 'translations',
    keySeparator: false,
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      formatSeparator: ','
    },
    react: {
      wait: true
    }
  });
  
export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer shown below.

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

    i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
        resources: {
             "en-MX": {
                   translations: {

                   }
             },
             "es-ES": {
                   translations: {

                   }
             },
             "zh-CN": {
                   translations: {

                   }
             },
             "zh-TW": {
                   translations: {

                   }
             }
     },
     fallbackLng: 'en',
     ns: ['translations'],
     defaultNS: 'translations',
     keySeparator: false,
     interpolation: {
       escapeValue: false,
       formatSeparator: ','
     },
     react: {
       wait: true
     }
  });
      
export default i18n;
```

Comment: fyi: the "react: { wait: true }" option is old  < v10